# Impact of not having life insurance on sponsoring B2 VISA for parents?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I am living in USA on H1B VISA. I would like to sponsor B2 VISA for my parents and my brother. I am filling I-134 affidavit forms for them, there I have to specify the value of my insurance coverage along bank deposits and other income.

I have recently changed my employer. Though I am eligible for life insurance, I have not been enrolled for life insurance because of mistake from HR department.

If I specify I have no insurance on I-134 form, does it impact B2 VISA approval decision?

Comment: Form asks about life insurance and its cash value. Don't worry about it; just use zero (or whatever the instructions say to do). Not everyone has life insurance.

Comment: @mkennedy,Life Insurance. I have health Insurance

Comment: This really isn't a travel question - should be on expats at best.

Comment: @MarkMayo Afaik, B2 visas are for holidays, so why shouldn't it be a travel question?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException ah, to me it was reading like he was living there and trying to get his parents to move out.  Fair enough, I retract my close vote!

Answer (score 2):

Opting for a life cover is completely up to the individual holding the work permit. It does not have any documented affect on the Affidavits of support (I-134) one submits to the USCIS